# Handle Dynamic Datatype in retrofit in android

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am using retrofit in my android application but my service sometimes return object data type and sometime array datatype. how can i handle this ? i used object in place of data type in android but am not able to use it properly.

Comment: It is bad api design if your backend returns different results for the same api call :-(
Ath the end try to create your own gson(?) parser http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/

Comment: let me check own gson parser

Answer (score 1):

Create an Interface,inside the Interface whenever your service returns a List do like this:

```
public Interface EndPointInterface{

 @GET(Constants.URL_GET_PHARMACY_REPORT)
    Call<List<PharmacyReport>> getPharmacyReport(@Query(Constants.PATIENT_ID) String patientId);

}
```

else if your service returns an Object proceed like this:

```
public Interface EndPointInterface{
    @GET(Constants.URL_FETCH_STORE_INFO)
        Call<Store> getStoreInfoByBeaconUUID(@Query(Constants.BEACON_UUID) String beaconUUID);
    }
```

Comment: but the same time it gives array and object

Comment: What is the Json response you are getting please post the response@Nitesh Sharma